# Outlook iCalendar Task Import/Export

Tags: outlook, task, icalendar, msg

I am attempting to write Task Items, for Outlook 2010, to an iCalendar file in order to be imported into Outlook.

I've looked through the specifications for both MS-OXCICAL and MS-OXCMSG (Calendar and Message) for Outlook and it appears as if they mention the ability to import/export tasks. The problem is that the only mention is in the Introduction and includes literally no explanation on the syntax or how to store Task Items in an ICS or MSG file.

Upon doing more research, VTODO was used for Task Items in the past and appears to no longer be supported as far as I can tell.

Any direction or help on this topic would be greatly appreciated!